# Validate model when it is created from json string in spring

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am preparing a model from a json string using json jackson object mapper in spring.

my code is

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String empValue =  mapper.writeValueAsString(employeeMap);
   Employees employee = mapper.readValue(empValue, Employees.class);
```

Before preparing object of employee i want to validate the json because if any mismatched data is set it through exception while preparing the model.How can i do it?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the use case.I guess employeeMap as employ as a value. So why it should not be valid if writeValueAsString did not throw any exception? Do you mean business validation?

Comment: Suppose,age is a property of a Employee class and i assigned a string value to this property.When object is being prepared from json it through a exception but from this exception i cant understand which property of employee is error prone

Comment: Can you specify the jackson and spring version you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can get some valuable information out of the exception mainly out of [JsonMappingException](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.4/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException.java) class and its sub classes (under the  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc package) using the **getPath** and **getPathReference** methods

Here are two examples:

```
public class ObjectMapperTest {
    private   ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrongDataType() {
        String personStr = "{\"age\":\"100Y\",\"firstName\":\"Jackson\",\"lastName\":\"Pollock\",\"gender\":\"M\"}";
        try {
            objectMapper.readValue(personStr, Person.class);
        } catch (JsonMappingException jme) {
                System.out.println(jme.getMessage());
                if(jme instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
                    InvalidFormatException ife = (InvalidFormatException)jme;
                    System.out.println("Mapping failure on field:" + ife.getPathReference());
                    System.out.println("Expected type: " + ife.getTargetType());
                    System.out.println("provided value: " + ife.getValue());
                }
        }catch (Exception  e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnrecognizedProperty() {
        String personStr = "{\"gae\":\"100\",\"firstName\":\"Jackson\",\"lastName\":\"Pollock\",\"gender\":\"M\"}";
        try {
            objectMapper.readValue(personStr, Person.class);
        } catch (JsonMappingException jme) {
            System.out.println(jme.getMessage());
            if(jme instanceof PropertyBindingException) {
                PropertyBindingException pbe = (PropertyBindingException) jme;
                System.out.println("Mapping failure on field:" + pbe.getPathReference());
                System.out.println("UnExpected field: " + pbe.getPropertyName());
            }
        }catch (Exception  e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
testUnrecognizedProperty:
========================
Unrecognized field "gae" (class Person), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "lastName", "gender", "firstName", "age"])
 at [Source: {"gae":"100","firstName":"Jackson","lastName":"Pollock","gender":"M"}; line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: Person["gae"])
Mapping failure on field:Person["gae"]
UnExpected field: gae
testWrongDataType:
======================== 
Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value '100Y': not a valid Integer value
 at [Source: {"age":"100Y","firstName":"Jackson","lastName":"Pollock","gender":"M"}; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: Person["age"])
Mapping failure on field:Person["age"]
Expected type: class java.lang.Integer
provided value: 100Y
```